# Convert comma separated string into XML with sequence number in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, xquery-sql

I am using SQL Server 2005. I have the following:

```
DECLARE @list NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @xml XML

SET @list = 'aa,bb,cc,dd,ee'
```

I would like to fill in @xml with data from the @list with the following format:

```
<row seq="1" col1="aa" />
<row seq="2" col1="bb" />
<row seq="3" col1="cc" />
<row seq="4" col1="dd" />
```

I tried to convert the @list into an XML string with the following:

```
SET @xml = '<row>' + REPLACE(@list, ',', '</row><row>') + '</row>'
```

and then tried to look for a FLWOR Expression in the @xml.query method that can add the sequence number for the rows, but I am out of luck as **there is no  let clause in SQL server 2005**. Could anyone give me a hint/workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using a split function...

```
DECLARE @list NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @xml XML

SET @list = 'aa,bb,cc,dd,ee'

;with cteSplit as(
    select * from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@list,',')),

cteFinal as(
select 
    '<row seq="' + cast(ItemNumber as varchar(64)) + '"  col1="' + Item + '" />' as Item
from cteSplit)

select Item from cteFinal --for XML AUTO
```

**[Here is the function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) which has proven to be a fast method of splitting strings:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K] (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!

RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN

/* "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)*/

  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Simon. There is function ROW_NUMBER() OVER... used here. I suspect that it may not keep the original list order in some special case, although its result appear to be correct?

Comment: It will keep the order according to the order of your elements in your comma separated string

Comment: In the cteTally, I think we should use function LEN() instead of DATALENGTH(), as LEN() can work with both NVARCHAR(x)  and VARCHAR(x) and it gives correct results in both cases. Just in case we want to change the parameters to NVARCHAR(x).

Comment: Ok @TuanLePN, feel free to do that. Just be aware that DATALENGTH includes trailing blank spaces where as LEN does not which could cause issue. I think this solved your problem though, no?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, when I looked at scSimon's answser the first time, I didn't like it. I had some bad experience with CROSS JOIN exponential blow up in the past (I ended up with a billion row table :-)). So, I decided to use a more comprehensive approach like the following:
1. Function to convert comma-separated list into XML:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Delimited2XML](@pList NVARCHAR(MAX), @pDelimiter NCHAR(1))
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @res NVARCHAR(MAX)    
    DECLARE @LEN INT
    SET @LEN = LEN(@pList)

    SET @res = '<root>'

    IF (@pList IS NOT NULL AND
        @LEN > 0 AND
        @pDelimiter IS NOT NULL AND
        LEN(@pDelimiter) > 0)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @startIdx INT
        DECLARE @curIdx INT
        SET @startIdx = 1
        SET @curIdx = 1

        DECLARE @i INT
        SET @i = 0

        WHILE @curIdx > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @i = @i + 1;
            SET @curIdx = CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter, @pList, @startIdx /*start_location*/)

            IF (@curIdx > 0)
            BEGIN
                -- create a xml node with this format: <row seq="i" item="item_i" />
                SET @res = @res + ('<row Seq="' + LTRIM(STR(@i)) + '" Item="' + SUBSTRING(@pList, @startIdx /*start*/, @curIdx - @startIdx /*length*/) + '" />')
                SET @startIdx = @curIdx + 1
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @res = @res + ('<row Seq="' + LTRIM(STR(@i)) + '" Item="' + SUBSTRING(@pList, @startIdx /*start*/, @LEN /*length*/) + '" />')
            END
        END

    END

    SET @res = @res + '</root>'
    RETURN CAST(@res AS XML)
END
```

2. Function to convert XML to table:

   CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit](@pString NVARCHAR(MAX), @pDelimiter NCHAR(1))
   RETURNS TABLE
   AS
   RETURN
   WITH tData
   AS
   (
       SELECT dbo.Delimited2XML(@pString, @pDelimiter) AS XMLData
   )
   SELECT Tab.XMLCol.value('@Seq', 'INTEGER') AS Seq,
       Tab.XMLCol.value('@Item', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Item
   FROM tData
   CROSS APPLY XMLData.nodes('/root/row') AS Tab(XMLCol)

I then tested the two functions, DelimitedSplit() and DelimitedSplit8K(), with a string that has 1200+ items. DelimitedSplit() took 240 ms to finish while DelimitedSplit8K() just took 20 ms, just 8% of DelimitedSplit()'s time. So, DelimitedSplit8K() has much better performance.